# Ext.Net.X.MessageBox' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: ext.net

when implementing this code and building the project I got the error someting like this.

Error   3'Ext.Net.X.MessageBox' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

am I doing someting wrong?
(I use visual studio,and .net4 framework)

```
  X.Msg.Confirm("Message", "Confirm?", new X.MessageBox.ButtonsConfig
            {
                Yes = new X.MessageBox.ButtonConfig
                {
                    Handler = "CompanyX.DoYes()",
                    Text = "Yes Please"
                },
                No = new X.MessageBox.ButtonConfig
                {
                    Handler = "CompanyX.DoNo()",
                    Text = "No Thanks"
                }
            }).Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use:

```
X.Msg.Confirm("Message", "Confirm?", new MessageBoxButtonsConfig()
{
    Yes = new MessageBoxButtonConfig()
    {
        Handler = "CompanyX.DoYes()",
        Text = "Yes Please"
    },
    No = new MessageBoxButtonConfig()
    {
        Handler = "CompanyX.DoNo()",
        Text = "No Thanks"
    }
}).Show();
```

Comment: is it possiable only return true or false depends on YesNo selection

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Please elaborate.

Comment: I am trying to create a class or method that somethink like this.      if (ConfirmMessagebox()==true)
            {

                //doing something
            }

            else { }